# Sort a range based on column "L" in ascending order

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I use the following macro recorded to sort Column L in Ascending order, but it seems a bit ridiculous to have to use 12 lines of code to sort something. Is there a more "efficient" way to do this?

I need it to sort the entire sheet, based on column L.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).AutoFilter
Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("L1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line will sort the L column in ascending order.

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Sort Key1:=Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

This will sort the ENTIRE sheet, to sort *just* the data, I'd declare a couple variables like below:

```
Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long, StartCell AS Range, s As Worksheet

Set s = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")
lastRow = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = s.Cells(StartCell.Row, s.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

s.Range(StartCell, s.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Sort _
 Key1:=Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

*Edited to reflect inclusion of ENTIRE sheet*

Comment: This works too although as stated above I realize I should just sort the entire sheet on column L instead of just doing L:BB

Comment: @CC268 see edit. I included the second option to sort all the DATA on your sheet by the L column

Comment: Did you mean to define StartCell somewhere? @SnWhte

Comment: @CC268 yes! Thank you. Updated it to include it, also updated it to make it a bit cleaner by adding the `s` variable for the worksheet

Comment: hmm I keep getting an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error as soon as I get to the lastRow line of code

Comment: @CC268 I always forget to put `Set` in front of ranges. See update, I just tested it so it should work now.

Comment: @CC268 glad to help!! Nice use of the Macro recorder to get you started

Answer (score 0):

If your data is starting in Row 1 and will stay in Row 1, you can just use this:

```
Columns.Sort key1:=Range("L1"), order1:=xlAscending
```

This will sort all columns based on the values in column L1.

Comment: That works perfectly - can we modify this so that it just sorts the entire sheet though instead of L:BB? I just realized that is what I need to do. Is there a way to specify the entire sheet vs. hard coding columns A through whatever my last column might be? @TylerH

Comment: @CC268 Heh, sure. I've updated my answer. I see you've gotten help from SnWhte too, though. Use whichever one works best for you.

Comment: Downvoter please care to comment on why you felt my answer was not useful, so that I can improve it?